# Slim 3 pagination with Twig view using Eloquent ORM

Tags: eloquent, twig, slim, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

I'm using Twig view for my slim 3 application but I don't know how to make pagination using the eloquent ORM below is my code.

MODEL:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Todo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "todo";
    protected $fillable = [
        'todo_name',
    ];
}
```

and this is my code to render a view

```
use App\Models\Todo;
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
    $data = Todo::all()->paginate(5);
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig', [
        'title' => 'Home',
        'todolist' => $data,
    ]);
})->setName('homepage');
```

and I got this error

```
Method paginate does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try $data = Todo::paginate(5);

Answer (score 0):

To use pagination you need `illuminate/pagination` package. It is not included by default when you include illuminate/database. You can use composer to include it in your project:

```
composer require illuminate/pagination
```

And you should not call paginate() method after a call to all() or get(). Try this instead:

```
$data=Todo::paginate(5);
```

And please note, for pagination to work correctly, it needs to know current page number otherwise it will always return results for first page. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211059/1788201) to see how to setup page resolver.

Comment: My bad. Missed something important in your question. I updated my answer but there is already a correct answer by @Lee