# Eloquent paginate function in Slim 3 project using twig

Tags: eloquent, twig, pagination, slim-3

How can I use paginate function from Eloquent in Slim 3 project using twig ?

This is in my controller :

```
$posts = Sound::paginate(2);

$this->container->view->render($response, 'admin/sounds/index.twig', [
  'posts' => $posts
]);
```

This is the view :

```
{{ posts.links() }}
```

But it doesn't work as well as I expected :

```
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in **PATH_TO_PROJECT**\vendor\illuminate\pagination\AbstractPaginator.php on line 412

Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on null in **PATH_TO_PROJECT**\vendor\illuminate\pagination\LengthAwarePaginator.php on line 90
```

What I have to do to make it work ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for the late :

I didn't keep the project, I don't remember exactly how I did, but this : https://github.com/romanzipp/PHP-Slim-Pagination looks like what I did.

```
$app->get('/posts', function(Request $req,  Response $res, $args = []) use ($cache) {

   $page      = ($req->getParam('page', 0) > 0) ? $req->getParam('page') : 1;
   $limit     = 5; // Number of posts on one page
   $skip      = ($page - 1) * $limit;
   $count     = Post::getCount([]); // Count of all available posts

   return $this->view->render($res, 'post-list.twig', [
      'pagination'    => [
          'needed'        => $count > $limit,
          'count'         => $count,
          'page'          => $page,
          'lastpage'      => (ceil($count / $limit) == 0 ? 1 : ceil($count / $limit)),
          'limit'         => $limit,
       ],
       // return list of Posts with Limit and Skip arguments
       'posts'         => Post::getList([
          'limit'         => $limit,
          'skip'          => $skip,
       ])
   ]);
});
```

In template :

```
 {% if pagination.needed %}
    <div class="ui pagination menu">
        {% for i in 1..pagination.lastpage %}
           <a class="{% if i == pagination.page %}active{% endif %} item" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
       {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="ui container">
    {% for post in posts %}
       <a class="item">
            {# Post contents (title, url, ...) #}
       </a>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
{{ posts.links }}
```

I presume that `links` is a getter that returns links. If not, this won't work like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include illuminate/pagination in your project (it's not included with illuminate/database):

```
composer require illuminate/pagination
```

Now paginator needs to know how to resolve current page. You should make sure this is done before using paginator, I personally put it where I'm setting up dependencies:

```
// $container is application's DIC container.
// Setup Paginator resolvers                                                                                                                                                                                       
Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::currentPageResolver(function ($pageName = 'page') use ($container) {                                                                                                              

    $page = $container->request->getParam($pageName);                                                                                                                                                              

    if (filter_var($page, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false && (int) $page >= 1) {                                                                                                                                    
        return $page;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

Then in your twig template you can output pagination links. But please you should notice that paginator generates some HTML code which needs to be written to output *as is* so you'll need to tell twig to ignore escaping for links:

```
{{ posts.links | raw }}
```

Comment: Hi, good to know, but I made my own paginate system. I didn't try your solution.

Comment: It would be nice  to post your solution, so others will know there are alternate ways to achieve this.

Comment: Can you tell more about Container ?

Comment: Where did you add this piece of code? I'm using he slim skeleton and added it to dependencies but it doesn't change much.

Comment: depwndencies.php is a good place for it. What is the exact problem with your code?